# how write the for loop for variable which have different name

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to calculate the MSE for different prediction which are done using different equations and want to save in excel sheet according predicting equation. Please suggest me how i use for loop and how to save all MSE values in single excel sheet.
Here i write my code which i want to complete

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Phd_3_yr_start/kanwar_ka_bas/Rabi_19_20_index/testing/testing.xlsx',  sheet_name = '9_feb')

productivity = df.iloc[:,0]
wdrvi = df.iloc[:,1]
cvi = df.iloc[:,2]
ndvi = df.iloc[:,3]
tndvi = df.iloc[:,4]
ndwi2 = df.iloc[:,5]
prediction_1 = 3.24+0.37*cvi
prediction_2 = 62.15*ndvi + 2.64*cvi + 32.79*ndwi2*tndvi - 28.09 - 22.37*tndvi - 31.29*ndwi2 - 62.19*wdrvi
prediction_3 = 2.45 + 4.06*ndvi
prediction_4 = 3.45 + 2.49*ndwi2
prediction_5 = 8.48*tndvi - 3.86
prediction_6 = 5.14 + 2.76*wdrvi
prediction_7 = 9.46 + 0.37*cvi*ndwi2 + 2.76*cvi*ndwi2*wdrvi - 1.08*cvi - 18.36*wdrvi**2
prediction_8 = 2.43 + 16.21*ndvi + 0.15*cvi**2 - 2.38*cvi
prediction_9 = 1.85 + 19.37*ndvi + 2.77*cvi*ndwi2 - 2.21*cvi - 17.34*ndvi*ndwi2
prediction_10 = 15.09*ndvi - 4.89 - 8.01*wdrvi
prediction_11 = 4.47 + 11.75*ndvi - 0.57*cvi - 3.99*tndvi
prediction_12 = 24.69*ndvi + 0.73*cvi - 10.57 - 4.24*tndvi - 19.69*wdrvi
prediction_13 = ndwi2 + 29.88*ndvi + 1.24*cvi - 17.24 - 4.24*tndvi - 28.64*wdrvi
prediction_14 = 36.54*ndvi + 1.15*cvi*ndwi2 - 14.67 - 2.93*ndwi2 - 6.07*tndvi - 28.05*wdrvi

MSE = np.square(np.subtract(productivity,prediction_i)).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to loop through the predictions, you can create a dictionary in Python and store each value as follows:

```
prediction_dict = {}
prediction_dict['prediction_1'] = 3.24+0.37*cvi
.
.
```

and so on.

You can loop through that dictionary using:

```
for key in prediction_dict:
    print(key)
    print(prediction_dict[key])
```

And, if you want to write it to an Excel file, then you can do:

```
prediction_list = list(prediction_dict.items())
df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_list)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question, but I want to calculate the mean square error between predicted productivity and observed productivity here I store observed predictivity in "productivity = df.iloc[:,0]".  so for that I want to for loop that means i want MSE for every eqation .